# *ERROR* Cannot find a backlight controller

Tags: backlight

So I just updated my kernel version on Ubuntu 15.04 64bit to Kernel 4.1.6 latest mainline.
Now every boot of my laptop, I got this error.

```
starting version 219
_
...screen blink...

starting version 219
[ 15.450992 ] [drm:radeon_acpi_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Cannot find a backlight controller
```

But after I login into my desktop, seems fine.
I can adjust my screen brightness very fine using keyboard shortcut.

Any advice on the error that pop-up on initial boot-up?

Comment: I have the same. I hope someone can provide an answer soon. It spans across distros I'm afraid. Fedora, Antergos, all give the same error for me as well.

Comment: Same thing happen on 4.1.6.